# How do I serialize an object for the query in a GET request?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to serialize an object in JavaScript so that I can query it in a GET request.

Comment: what have you done ? How does the Object in memory look ? Javascript objects can be converted to JSON (Javascript Object Notation). `JSON.stringify(<your JS object>)` will convert your Javascript Object to a string and you can do whatever you like with the JSON String like save it to a file or send it etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way, as per the standard, is:

```
function serialise(obj) {
    serialised = '';
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        serialised += encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/%20/g, '+') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]).replace(/%20/g, '+') + '&';
    });
    return serialised.slice(0, -1);
}

var queryString = serialise({key: 'value', key2: 'value2'});
```

`encodeURIComponent` encodes the string safe for `x-www-form-urlencoded` in the URL and GET requests (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?**key=value**) except it replaces spaces with `%20` rather than `+`, so a final `.replace` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do it using jQuery:

```
var obj = {'test' : 1, 'other' : 2};

console.log( $.param($obj) );
```